# XML Schema Choice and attribute

Tags: xml, layout, xsd

I have a little problem I would like an attribute to act as a member_id.

This is becuase if I have it as just another tag I can't get it total unique I can only get it unique for all full_member type and basic_member type.

so I thought I could solve this with an attribute and a key.

But my problem is that I can't have a attribute and a choice next to each other or I just don't know how to do it right.

Below is my schema so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  
    <xs:complexType name="memberinfo">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="member_id"/>
        <xs:element ref="first_name"/>
        <xs:element ref="last_name"/>
        <xs:element ref="address"/>
        <xs:element ref="contact_numbers"/>
        <xs:element ref="date_joined"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  
  <xs:element name="member_id" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="first_name" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="last_name" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="address">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice>
        <xs:element ref="house_number"/>
        <xs:element ref="house_name"/>
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:element ref="street"/>
        <xs:element ref="town"/>
        <xs:element ref="city"/>
        <xs:element ref="county"/>
        <xs:element ref="postcode"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="house_number" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="house_name" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="town" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="city" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="county" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="postcode" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="contact_numbers">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="3" ref="contact_number"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="contact_number" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="date_joined" type="xs:date"/>
  
 <xs:complexType name="basic_member">
   <xs:complexContent>
     <xs:extension base="memberinfo">
       <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="activities">
           <xs:complexType>
             <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element name="activity_name" maxOccurs="3"/>
             </xs:sequence>
           </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
       </xs:sequence>
     </xs:extension>
   </xs:complexContent>
 </xs:complexType>
  
  <xs:complexType name="full_member">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="memberinfo">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="activities">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="activity_name" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  
  <xs:element name="members" >
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="member" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="member_id"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:key name="PK_member">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//member" />
      <xs:field xpath="member_id" />
    </xs:key>
  </xs:element>
    
</xs:schema>
```

Example of entry

```
<member>
    <full_member>
        <member_id>1</member_id>
        <first_name>Simon</first_name>
        <last_name>Hughes</last_name>
        <address>
            <house_number>12</house_number>
            <street>Ashgrove Road</street>
            <town>Forest Town</town>
            <city>Mansfield</city>
            <county>Nottinghamshire</county>
            <postcode>NG385DX</postcode>
        </address>
        <contact_numbers>
            <contact_number>01623948594</contact_number>
            <contact_number>01623349596</contact_number>
            <contact_number>01623486599</contact_number>
        </contact_numbers>
        <date_joined>2012-05-21</date_joined>
        <activities>
            <activity_name>Treadmill</activity_name>
            <activity_name>Squash</activity_name>
            <activity_name>Table Tennis</activity_name>
            <activity_name>Weights</activity_name>
        </activities>
    </full_member>
    </member>
    
    <member>
    <full_member>
        <member_id>2</member_id>
        <first_name>Scott</first_name>
        <last_name>Calladine</last_name>
        <address>
            <house_name>Don House</house_name>
            <street>Simons Road</street>
            <town>Broadton</town>
            <city>Supper</city>
            <county>Nottinghamshire</county>
            <postcode>N496DX</postcode>
        </address>
        <contact_numbers>
            <contact_number>01623395865</contact_number>
            <contact_number>01623496959</contact_number>
            <contact_number>01623005604</contact_number>
        </contact_numbers>
        <date_joined>2007-08-16</date_joined>
        <activities>
            <activity_name>Static Cycle</activity_name>
            <activity_name>Badminton</activity_name>
            <activity_name>Table Tennis</activity_name>
        </activities>
    </full_member>
    </member>

<member>
    <full_member>
        <member_id>3</member_id>
        <first_name>Fransis</first_name>
        <last_name>Smith</last_name>
        <address>
            <house_name>Don House</house_name>
            <street>Lemington Close</street>
            <town>Bradford</town>
            <city>Bradfordcity>
            <county>West Yorkshire</county>
            <postcode>BD723DX</postcode>
        </address>
        <contact_numbers>
            <contact_number>01623497035</contact_number>
            <contact_number>01623389468</contact_number>
            <contact_number>01623439949</contact_number>
        </contact_numbers>
        <date_joined>2007-08-16</date_joined>
        <activities>
            <activity_name>Static Cycle</activity_name>
            <activity_name>Badminton</activity_name>
            <activity_name>Table Tennis</activity_name>
        </activities>
    </full_member>
    </member>

<member>
    <full_member>
        <member_id>4</member_id>
        <first_name>Hayley</first_name>
        <last_name>Cummingham</last_name>
        <address>
            <house_number>87</house_number>
            <street>Boreast Road</street>
            <town>Braranger</town>
            <city>Mansfield</city>
            <county>Nottinghamshire</county>
            <postcode>N454HX</postcode>
        </address>
        <contact_numbers>
            <contact_number>01623306031</contact_number>
            <contact_number>01623206940</contact_number>
            <contact_number>01623059680</contact_number>
        </contact_numbers>
        <date_joined>2012-05-21</date_joined>
        <activities>
            <activity_name>Treadmill</activity_name>
            <activity_name>Squash</activity_name>
            <activity_name>Table Tennis</activity_name>
            <activity_name>Weights</activity_name>
        </activities>
    </full_member>
    </member>
```

but with my current schema the id's would go `1 ,1 ,2 ,2`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "This is becuase if I have it as just another tag I can't get it total unique I can only get it unique for all full_member type and basic_member type." Could you elaborate on the problem?

Comment: becasue i am using two other complex types full_member and basic_member i can only make the member_id's unique for each for exmaple there will be a full member with id 1 and a basic member with id 1. a full member with 2 and basic with 2 and so on. what i want it to do is go full 1 basic 2 full 3 basic 4 . these ful and basic can be entered in any order E/g basic full full basic full basic basic but i wud need the ids to go 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7

Comment: It would probably be easier to comprehend if you could provide a short example of sample input that you would like to validate.

Comment: Is there a reason you have two separate tags `<basic_member>` and `<full_member>` instead of one tag `<member type="full">`? Also, you should really use attributes for singular tags like `first_name` and `last_name`. So instead of `<member><full_member><first_name>Hayley</first_name><last_name>Cunningham</last_name>...</full_member></member>` it would be `<member type="full" first_name="Hayley" last_name="Cunningham">...</member>`

Comment: a basic member can only have up to three activities and a full member can have a unlimited maoutn that why these is two sepearte ones. and i have always read its a bad idea to put everything into attributes

Comment: Attributes are useful for 3 reasons 1) They limit the input to one value 2) They are easier to access when using a SAX parser and 3) In a DOM parser each element creates a new node in the DOM tree so using attributes saves memory, especially in large files. Doing a simple profiling test (in Python using `xml.dom.minidom` and `cProfile`) over 100,000 items defined using no attributes and 100,000 elements defined using attributes, I clocked `14000235 function calls in 44.210 seconds` using only elements and `5200235 function calls in 28.140 seconds` using attributes with elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do it:

```
<xs:key name="PK_member"> 
  <xs:selector xpath=".//basic_member|.//full_member" /> 
  <xs:field xpath="member_id" /> 
</xs:key>
```

but there appear to be something wrong in your schema - or at least, it does not match your sample XML. In the schema `members` contain a `member` element that has just one attribute, and there are two separate - and unrelated - `full_member` and `basic_member` elements, whereas in your XML file `basic_member` and `full_member` show up inside `member`.